# How to test a React functional component that loads data during mount

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to have different unit tests to test the different states of my component and it's interaction with an async request. I am having alot of difficulty doing so. Most documentation says to "simulate" the event that triggers the async state change (i.e. simulate a click of a component), however, my state is supposed to change on component load and not by any user interaction. I have seen reference to the `act` function (https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html#testing-hooks) but I don't know how to implement it in this context.

Here is my functional react component:

```
import { useRequest } from '@umijs/hooks' // Request custom hook

// An async function that does an async task to get data
async function someAsyncFunctionToFetch() => {
    return Promise.resolve({data: 'data'})
}

// The functional component
export function TestComponent() {
  const { data, error, loading } = useRequest(FulfillmentService.getFullfillmentServices)

  const loadingMarkup = (
    <p>Loading</p>
  )

  const errorMarkup = (
    <p>Error</p>
  )

  const contentMarkup = (
    <p>{ data }</p>
  )

  if (loading) {
    return loadingMarkup
  } else if (error) {
    return errorMarkup
  } else if (!isEmpty(data)) {
    return contentMarkup
  } else {
    return <p>Some empty state</p>
  }
}
```

These are the tests that I want to achieve:

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
    it.todo('when data is loading the loading markup should be rendered')
    it.todo('when data fetching results in an error the error markup should be rendered')
    it.todo('when data fetching returns with valid data the content markup should be rendered')
    it.todo('when data fetching returns an empty data object the empty state markup should be rendered')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the component renders the desired markup for each state you can mock the return value of the `useRequest` hook. This can be achieved using the [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules) function to mock the behaviour of the `@umijs/hooks` module:

```js
import { useRequest } from "@umijs/hooks";

jest.mock("@umijs/hooks");
```

Now each state can be simulated using the [`mockReturnValue`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue) function. For example to mock the loading state we would do:

```js
useRequest.mockReturnValue({ 
  loading: true 
});
```

The tests for each scenario would look something along the lines of:

```js
import { useRequest } from "@umijs/hooks";

jest.mock("@umijs/hooks");

describe("TestComponent", () => {
  describe("loading description", () => {
    beforeEach(() => useRequest.mockReturnValue({ loading: true }));

    it("loading assertion", () => {/* ... */});
  });

  describe("error description", () => {
    beforeEach(() => useRequest.mockReturnValue({ error: "Given error" }));

    it("error assertion", () => {/* ... */});
  });

  describe("valid data description", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      useRequest.mockReturnValue({ data: { value: "Given data" }});
    });

    it("valid data assertion", () => {/* ... */});
  });

  describe("empty data description", () => {
    beforeEach(() => useRequest.mockReturnValue({ data: {} }));

    it("empty data assertion", () => {/* ... */});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up doing. Rather than mocking the module directly, I ended up using a DI pattern to pass a mocked function as a prop to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to abstract out `FulfillmentService.getFullfillmentServices` either by moving it to your `props` or create a context. That way you can easily mock each response from `FulfillmentService.getFullfillmentServices`.

The second option would be to use [`nock`](https://github.com/nock/nock) and intercept `FulfillmentService.getFullfillmentServices`'s api call.